# Dropdownlist Listitems submit to Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, drop-down-menu

I'm just learning to program...I have a dropdownlist like this.

```
<div>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem >Alabama</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem >Alaska</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList></div>
```

Using C# I want to send the selected item to database. Database field is `County nvarchar(50) NULL`,

I saw some example in C# backend .I found this one on the internet.Can i send above selected item from below coding ?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

       ListItem[] items = new ListItem[3];
       items[0] = new ListItem("One", "1");
       items[1] = new ListItem("Two", "2");
       items[2] = new ListItem("Three", "3");

       DropDownList1.Items.AddRange(items);
```

Comment: Actually i cannot understand wht you are looking for.

Comment: you want to save dropdownlist selected value to database?

Comment: what is the database SQL SERVER?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  List<ListItem> items = new List<ListItem>();
  items.Add(new ListItem("Alabama", "Alabama"));
  items.Add(new ListItem("Alaska", "Alaska"));
  DropDownList1.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray());
```

if you want to get selected items from DropDownList1

```
var selectedText = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;

var selectedValue = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;
```

if you need to insert this value to database then

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tableName (County) VALUES (@County)";

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@County", selectedText);

    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Where thisone write? ASP page or C# page(aspx.cs) ?

Answer (score 1):

If You Want to Add item from DB to your drop down then you can use

```
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(" your connection string ");
 conn.Open();
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from ddltable ", conn);
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 da.Fill(ds, " ddltable ");
 DropDownList1.DataSource = ds.Tables["ddltable "].DefaultView ;
 DropDownList1.DataTextField = "id";
 DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Place this code in your pageload

Or If you want to select item from drop down then you can enable postback and also use

```
DropDownList1.selectedItem
```

Use This code

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);

        con.Open();

        for (int i = 0; i < DropDownList1.Items.Count; i++)

        {

            if (DropDownList1.Items[i].Selected == true)

            {

                str = "insert into employee1 values('" + DropDownList1.Items[i].ToString() + "')";

                com = new SqlCommand(str, con);

                com.ExecuteNonQuery();

                Response.Write("<script>alert('Items Inserted');</script>");

            }

        }
```

Comment: Actually I'm confuzing there.In here you did load data to the Dropdownlist from database know ?

Comment: yes, This is for loading data from the DB. If you want to add data to your DB same process. 1-Create a DB connection, 2- Execute a insert query(That having selected vale).

Comment: please update answer to match that ..It's prettymuch helpful to me

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
DropDownList1.SelectedValue
```

or

```
DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value
```

To get the selected value from your Drop down list